# k nearest neighbors method, temporal trend in error

Tags: dataset, data, error-handling

I have this set of data that looks like this

[image: data]

I was asked o build a $k$-nearest neighbors algorithm for it which I just finished building. I have this question in regards to the data that I do not understand: Do you notice any spatial or temporal trends in error?

I am not sure how to proceed in answering that question. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to build a -nearest neighbors algorithm, you need to define a distance metric that predicts the closest observed data points for a given data point.

For latitude and longitude, [great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).

For time, the distance metric is often days, seconds, or fractions of seconds.

-nearest neighbors algorithm has no notion of error. Given that there are only a couple of variables, it would be straightforward to do a plot of the when predicting for a new data point.